# Can we use "by the favour of"?

Tags: prepositions

We are familiar with the expression *'by the grace of'.* 'Favour' also means grace. So, is it correct to use *'by the favour of'*? Consider my sentence:

1. *I earned the job by the favour of luck.*

That is: *I earned the job **by** (the favour of) **luck***, or "*Luck favoured me to get the job."*

2. *I earned my degrees **by** the favour of circumstances.*

I mean, *'Circumstances favoured me to obtain my degrees'*.Here *'luck'* and *'circumstances'* are agents (personifications).  How should I express the meaning of the above sentences?

Comment: by the favor of is not idiomatic in English, really.

Answer (score 1):

*I got the job by good luck.* If it was simply by luck, you didn't do anything to *earn* it, and good luck is by definition a favour, so it doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: You're right that 'got' is more appropriate. But, suppose, I want to use "luck' as an agent, as in the case of personification?

Comment: _By good luck_ is all you need.